# How can I deny all users except one to invoke API in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

Is there a way/policy using which I can deny all users except one who can invoke an API endpoint at AWS API Gateway?

Policy currently used:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account_id:user/user-name"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account_id:api_to_be_invoked/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I applied the above policy at the API Gateway's Resource Policy and deployed it, but then, just to test, I tried using another admin user's access and secret key to POST through Postman, and it still successfully did, which I do not want.

Any help?

Comment: Reverse the logic and use explicit DENY with NotPrincipal. An explicit deny always wins in IAM policies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": 
                    [  "arn:aws:iam::account_id:user/user-name",
                       "arn:aws:iam::account_id:root"
                    ]
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account_id:api_to_be_invoked/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting error for that user also which is inside NotPrincipal, error:

{
    "Message": "User: arn:aws:iam::account_id:user/user-name is not authorized to perform: execute-api:region:account_id:api_to_be_invoked/test/POST/abcd with an explicit deny"
}

Comment: FYI - 'AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess' policy is explicitly attached to that user as of now, to be on the safer side, still the above error.

Comment: I think the third row of Table A of this link is what is happening in my case: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-authorization-flow.html#apigateway-resource-policies-iam-policies-interaction. Any help what extra I need to do to fix it?

Comment: I figured out and fixed it. Answer to the above problem is I had to also add root in the list of NotPrincipal section along with the user. AWS Documentation suggests:  "If the NotPrincipal element contained only Bob's ARN, the effect of the policy might be to explicitly deny access to the AWS account that contains the user Bob. In some cases, a user cannot have more permissions than its parent account, so if Bob's account is explicitly denied access then Bob might be unable to access the resource."

Comment: Suggest you to please also add root in the NotPrincipal section of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AakashBasu!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use **IAM Policies Conditions**?
I haven't tried it in a production environment but it should fulfil your need.

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account_id:api_to_be_invoked/*/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals" : {
               "aws:username" : "your_user_name"
             }
          }
    }
]}
```

Please let me know if this answer helped.